# $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial Ax}=?$

Tags: calculus, matrices

How can we calculate $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial Ax}$ for square matrix $A$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

For example, we have $\frac{\partial{x^TAx}}{\partial{x}}=2x^TA$.

Comment: What have you tried.

Comment: <telepathy>inverse function theorem</telepathy>

Comment: It would be good that you explain us the meaning of your symbol!

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ denotes a vector, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ denotes a constant matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x = A^{-1}Ax$. Try substituting that in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! $\frac{\partial{A^{-1}Ax}}{\partial{Ax}}=A^{-1}$? What if $A$ is a singular matrix?

Comment: @jacobian86 then this isn't defined. Kinda like asking in 1d for $\frac{dx}{d(ax)}$ when $a=0$.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you!

Comment: are you sure $\frac{\partial{A^{-1}Ax}}{\partial{Ax}}=A^{-1}$ is correct as $A^{-1}$ is not a constant wrt. $Ax$?

Comment: @zyxue $A^{-1}$ is a constant, it cannot have a nonzero derivative. Equivalently, what you would be saying in 1D is that $k$ is not a constant w.r.t. $kx$ for $k$ a constant.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood. you're right